# React-Navigation header icons touching android statusbar

Tags: android, react-native, mobile, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I am currently trying to make the statusbar transparent and it's working absolutely perfect on iOS but on Android, the react-navigation header is going behind it and thus making the title and left/right menu icons touching the statusbar, not sure how to add extra gap between it and make it look like earlier.

I have just added translucent and backgroundColor="transparent" on statusbar to make it work.

Please provide me a generic solution so that the change should occur throughout the application

I want the statusbar to be transparent as I am using backgroundImage

[image]

Comment: Are you using react-navigation v5?

Comment: @IanVasco - No, "react-navigation": "3.2.1" and I can't able to upgrade it right now